# What conditions would cause electricity to create carbon monoxide?

Tags: chemistry, electricity, electromagnetism, gas

I've been mulling whether the local gaseous makeup of air is changed by electricity running along a wire. My previous question is on hold, and this one is different anyway.

I couldn't find exactly what I needed on google. The corona effect is close, but on my fictional world the composition of the air is much higher in oxygen. It's not earth. There are two suns, and solar output is weaker. The ice caps are enormous. Some of the help I received on the previous question suggested corona effect. That might work but doesn't really make carbon - containing gases.

The best gas for my world based on the inhabitants (which breathe oxygen but are more severely impacted by carbon monoxide) would be carbon monoxide. Combustion makes this, but not sure electrical arcing would.

Specifically, I need an electric fence to create a gas (CO ideally) that is different in concentration from the surrounding air, by virtue of whether the fence is on or not. I can work with other gases which is why I didn't constrain it before.

I've received tremendous input from the community on the meta forum. Thank you in advance for your help. I've really been struggling with this.

You guys are awesome.

Comment: I'm not sure this question differs enough from your previous question to not be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Would it be better to paste this text over the previous question? I am simply accommodating all the fantastic feedback from the meta discussions. Hoping to get back to a useful place! Thanks so much,  very appreciated.

Comment: @frostfyre said and was upvoted that **"There's a difference between asking, "How can I leverage known science to get desired effect X?" (a worldbuilding question) and, "Can this known science get desired effect X?" (a science question)."** Here, I am asking how to leverage, exactly as frostfyre said to do.

Comment: Do you want every wire on the planet to cause this effect, or one specific set in particular?

Comment: One specific set in particular. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of asking an extremely similar question, I'd suggest editing your previous question to be about worldbuilding or to migrate it to [chemistry.se]

Comment: Alright I'll paste this over the previous one and see if that fixes things. This should be interesting.

Comment: If your atmosphere is higher in oxygen, it would be virtually impossible to create significant amounts of carbon monoxide from it. Your fence should be coming with supply of some chemical that would yield CO when electricity is on.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate of your previous question because it is **literally an exact copy of that one** except for the tags. Please don't post the same question multiple times. Also, please don't make answer-invalidating edits. Edits that substantially or completely invalidate existing answers may be rolled back.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I rolled his last edit on his previous question back, and pasted the 4th edit in at the bottom, instead of replacing all the text. I don't know if that makes this one less of a duplicate, since that one was about altering air chemistry in general, and this one is about generating CO in particular?

Comment: @AndyD273 That you did. I have reopened this as it's not really a duplicate in its current form; however, I'm not convinced it's a great question (I'm also not convinced it's a bad enough question to be nailed shut, particularly unilaterally). But at least this way, if it does end up closed, the close reason can indicate the proper reason.

Comment: @Michael Kjorling literally right up above, in this comments section, you can see that I was advised to edit the other question with this text. Thus, I followed instructions and pasted this text into the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is specifically for one set of wires, and carbon monoxide is caused by burning, then this set of wires could have a coating that is slowly burning when the power is on.
It could be an insulator that is just breaking down and buring under the very high current, or it could be some pollution that has built up on the wire that burns off when it is powered up.

[image]

This would especially be true if there was a short somewhere along the line, which could cause the wire to heat up much higher than normal.

Comment: Thank you Andy. That is a very good idea. The picture is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown

> Electrical breakdown occurs within a gas when the dielectric strength
>   of the gas is exceeded. Regions of intense voltage gradients can cause
>   nearby gas to partially ionize and begin conducting.

Ozone is a familiar such gas: O2 is split and the O- molecules glom on to unspilt O2 to form O3.

http://www.oxidationtech.com/ozone/ozone-production/corona-discharge.html
[image: ozone generation]

If O2 can be electrically broken down so can CO2 - rip off an O and let it find another one to make O2.

from
http://carbon.atomistry.com/decomposition_carbon_dioxide.html

> Carbon dioxide is decomposed into carbon monoxide and oxygen by means
>   of electric sparks, a fact first observed by Henry; whilst Buff and
>   Hofmann found that the decomposition is more rapid if steel electrodes
>   are used, since these combine with the liberated oxygen. Even then,
>   however, the decomposition is not complete, but it rises to 65 per
>   cent, when the pressure is reduced to 1 mm. The silent electric
>   discharge, ultra-violet light, and radium rays also decompose carbon
>   dioxide.

"Silent electric discharge" is a [dielectric field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_barrier_discharge) as depicted in the ozone generator.  I think this uses less energy than a corona discharge.

There are people working on CO synthesis from CO2.  You use a feedstock of pure CO2 (like the ozone generator uses feedstock of pure O2) and even then it looks like less than 1% is converted to CO.

I propose that to help, your fence also incorporate ultraviolet light and "radium rays".  Get you some radium rays in that fence!  Clearly this text is taken from a more ancient source but [all of the public domain sources](http://atomistry.com/copyright) are listed in a mix.

Fence advice:

1: Dielectric discharge.
2:  Pure CO2 feed into generator
3: Help from UV and radium rays